# App crashes when I try to logout

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am developping an app and the user authenticats with google sign in.
Sign in is perfect but if I use

```
mAuth.signOut();
```

this signs me out of firebase and not from the google account. when I try to sign in it signs in with the account I used just before and I don't have the option to choose an account.
I followed the google documentation to sign out user and disconnect accounts.
my button code:

```
btnlogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                 signOut();
             }
         });
```

my signOut code

```
private void signOut() {
        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(TempActivity.this,MainActivity.class));


                    }
                });
    }
```

Button is inside onCreate. My app crashes when I Press the log out button. Any ideas? I get error when i call signout, java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Please post the logs for the crash

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException and it's the lines where I call signout,the mGoogleSignInClient.signout line and at the beginning where i declare public class..

Comment: Where are you initializing `mGoogleSignInClient`?

Comment: At the other class where the signIn is happpening mGoogleSignInClient=GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso)

Comment: You need to provide full crash stack trace.

Comment: Can you please add the whole `onCreate` code to your question?

Comment: please share your Signin Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you are referencing to the same `GoogleSignInClient` object. It looks to me that you are using another `GoogleSignInClient` object in the class that handles the logout which is not yet initialized and thereby causing a nullpointer exception.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .build();

mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

You then need to use the same reference to `mGoogleSignInClient` in the class that handles the logout.

Comment: added this code to the signout class and I get no error but it doesnt return me to the signIn activity

Comment: If you want to return to the sign in activity you need to call

startActivity(new Intent(currentActivity.this, loginActivity.class)) and change currentActivity and loginActivity to whatever you call them,

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, I called it in onStart()